# Integral Representations of Ramanujan theta functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integration

Ramanujan defined his function $\phi(x)$ as $$\phi(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{n^2}$$ and other one as $$\psi(q)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}q^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$$ So I have a question that is there an integral representation for these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [inverse Mellin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem), which allows you to pass from $q$-expansions to Dirichlet series. For instance, the first of the theta functions you have written down is essentially the inverse Mellin transform of $\zeta(2s)$ (a fact used by Riemann to prove the functional equation of the $\zeta$-function).

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution

Comment: @ShivamPatel I suggest you focus on getting the right tools to understand Riemann's paper. You should learn the basics of complex analysis. You are young, so you have time to do things right. Don't cut corners! I recommend Churchill & Brown's complex analysis book. If you can master this book by the time you are 16, you'll be on your way to great things!

Comment: @ShivamPatel My pleasure. Good luck!